# BLE android programming

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am facing problem in showing DATA received from Ble device in my application. as I am receiving a string and I want to show the  first- four byte in different text box and its not happening.

In short it comes out of the loop as soon as first display happens and again if I sends the data twice or thrice then it shows in second display box???? Please help..

I am receiving a hex packet so need check it s byte but my main concern is here after receiving data its shows only display1speed not the other. Only one statement works here

```
private void onReciveData(byte[] data) {
    Log.d("OnReceivedata called");
    if (data != null) {
        recv = new String(data);
        int Rpm_int = data[3] + data[4] * 256;
        String speed_int=null;
        display1speed.setText("" + speed_int);
        display2rpm.setText("" + Rpm_int);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting to char array ? I f you want 1st 4 characters you can use "subString" eg :recv.subString(0,4)..

Comment: please see again the above code

Comment: Can you check this .. 
recv = recv.subString(3,2);
display2rpm.setText(recv);

Comment: the above is not working... !1

Comment: question is not very clear.. but just assumption it might be because of thread, BluetoothGattCallback methods doesn't run on UIThread

Comment: thanks this problem is resolved.....

Comment: please tell is it possible to send data to the server received via bluetooth application within  the same application? if yes then how?